# FILE reading and sorting a link list

Tags: c

It seems my `FILE` reading function is slightly off. Instead of printing all the data (First Name: Last Name: priority: Reading Level:) per entry when I call my print function it stops after two and just has the skeleton of what needs to be printed there for the last three entries. And because of that, when I then call my sort function based off priority level in each `struct` link list, I can't tell if it's printing correctly.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NAME 25
#define TITLE 50

typedef struct Book{
    int bookID;
    char* title;
    bool checkedOut;
    struct Book* next;
}book;


typedef struct Student{
    char* firstName;
    char* lastName;
    int priority;
    int readingLevel;
    book* backPack;
    bookids* wishlist;
    struct Student* next;
}student;

student* buildStudentList(char* studentFile, student* head)
{
    FILE *cfptr=fopen(studentFile, "r");
    if(cfptr==NULL){
        printf("\nFIle could not be opened\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if(head==NULL){
        head=malloc(sizeof(student));
        head->next=NULL;
        head->firstName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
        head->lastName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
        fscanf(cfptr,"%s %s %d %d", head->firstName,head->lastName, 
                &head->priority, &head->readingLevel);
    }
    student* current=head;
    while(current->next!=NULL){
        current=current->next;
    }
    current->next=malloc(sizeof(student));
    current=current->next;
    current->firstName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
    current->lastName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
    while( fscanf(cfptr, "%s %s %d %d", current->firstName, current->lastName, 
            &current->priority, &current->readingLevel)!=EOF){
        student* current=head;
        while(current->next!=NULL){
            current=current->next;
        }
        current->next=malloc(sizeof(student));
        current=current->next;
        current->firstName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
        current->lastName=malloc(sizeof(student)*35);
    }
    return head;
}


void createPriorityQueue(student* head)
{
    if(head==NULL ||head->next==NULL){
        return;
    }
    student* curr; student* largest; student* largestPrev; student* prev;
    curr=head;
    largest=head;
    prev=head;
    largestPrev=head;
    while(curr!=NULL){
        if(&curr->priority>&largest->priority){
            largestPrev=prev;
            largest=curr;
        }
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    student* tmp;
    if(largest!=head)
    {
        largestPrev->next=head;
        tmp=head->next;
        head->next=tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please _indent_ your code. It is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few bugs.

The `malloc` for allocation of strings should be `malloc(35)` and *not* `malloc(sizeof(student) * 35)`. It won't crash but it's wasteful.

Your build function was way too complicated and had several bugs--I had to recode it.

Your priority queue function was comparing *addresses* of `priority` instead of *values* [what we want].

Anyway, here's your code with some annotations for the bugs and a recoded create function [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME 25
#define TITLE 50

typedef struct Book {
    int bookID;
    char *title;
    bool checkedOut;
    struct Book *next;
} book;

typedef struct Student {
    char *firstName;
    char *lastName;
    int priority;
    int readingLevel;
    book *backPack;
    bookids *wishlist;
    struct Student *next;
} student;

// NOTE/BUG: this function is way to complicated -- see below for a simpler one
student *
buildStudentList(char *studentFile, student * head)
{
    FILE *cfptr = fopen(studentFile, "r");

    if (cfptr == NULL) {
        printf("\nFIle could not be opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if (head == NULL) {
        head = malloc(sizeof(student));
        head->next = NULL;

// NOTE/BUG: we want just enough to store strings -- this is true for all the
// other mallocs that allocate names
#if 0
        head->firstName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);
        head->lastName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);
#else
        head->firstName = malloc(35);
        head->lastName = malloc(35);
#endif

        fscanf(cfptr, "%s %s %d %d",
            head->firstName, head->lastName, &head->priority,
            &head->readingLevel);
    }

    student *current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = malloc(sizeof(student));
    current = current->next;
    current->firstName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);
    current->lastName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);

    while (fscanf(cfptr, "%s %s %d %d",
        current->firstName, current->lastName, &current->priority,
        &current->readingLevel) != EOF) {
        student *current = head;

        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = malloc(sizeof(student));
        current = current->next;
        current->firstName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);
        current->lastName = malloc(sizeof(student) * 35);
    }

    // NOTE/BUG: close input file
#if 1
    fclose(cfptr);
#endif

    return head;
}

// simplified version
student *
buildStudentList(char *studentFile, student * head)
{
    FILE *cfptr = fopen(studentFile, "r");
    student *current;
    student *tail;
    char firstName[5000];
    char lastName[5000];

    if (cfptr == NULL) {
        printf("\nFIle could not be opened\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // find last element in list
    tail = NULL;
    for (current = head;  current != NULL;  current = current->next)
        tail = current;

    while (1) {
        // allocate new node
        current = malloc(sizeof(student));

        // initialize the next pointer (in a singly linked list, this is nulled)
        current->next = NULL;

        // get data for new node
        if (fscanf(cfptr, "%s %s %d %d",
            firstName, lastName, &current->priority,
            &current->readingLevel) == EOF) {
            free(current);
            break;
        }

        // allocate space for strings
        current->firstName = strdup(firstName);
        current->lastName = strdup(lastName);

        // add to empty list
        if (head == NULL)
            head = current;

        // add to tail of list
        else
            tail->next = current;

        // set this as new tail of list
        tail = current;
    }

    fclose(cfptr);

    return head;
}

void
createPriorityQueue(student * head)
{
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    student *curr;
    student *largest;
    student *largestPrev;
    student *prev;

    curr = head;
    largest = head;
    prev = head;
    largestPrev = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
// NOTE/BUG: this compares _addresses_ but we want to compare values
#if 0
        if (&curr->priority > &largest->priority) {
#else
        if (curr->priority > largest->priority) {
#endif
            largestPrev = prev;
            largest = curr;
        }
        prev = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    student *tmp;

    if (largest != head) {
        largestPrev->next = head;
        tmp = head->next;
        head->next = tmp;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> how do I make the createpriority function sort in the opposite order, its form highest to lowest, i need lowest to highest?

Not sure exactly which order you want now or what changes you've already made. In your original code, you were only doing a *single* pass on the list instead of as many passes as there were elements.

I've fixed the original code to do the correct number of passes, using simple insertion/selection. This is slow. You could speed it up by doing a mergesort on the linked list, but that's more involved.

Anyway, here's the code. I didn't test it or even compile it but it should get you closer:

```
student *
createPriorityQueue(student *head)
{
    student *curr;
    student *bestCurr;
    student *bestPrev;
    student *prev;
    student *tail;
    student *rtn;

    // initialize sorted list
    rtn = NULL;
    tail = NULL;

    // process all elements of unsorted list
    while (head != NULL) {
        // assume head of unsorted list is best priority in unsorted list
        bestCurr = head;
        bestPrev = NULL;

        // find best in unsorted list
        prev = NULL;
        for (curr = head;  curr != NULL;  curr = curr->next) {
#ifdef SORT_LOW_TO_HIGH
            if (curr->priority < bestCurr->priority) {
                bestCurr = curr;
                bestPrev = prev;
            }
#else
            if (curr->priority > bestCurr->priority) {
                bestCurr = curr;
                bestPrev = prev;
            }
#endif
            prev = curr;
        }

        // remove element from unordered list
        if (bestPrev != NULL)
            bestPrev->next = bestCurr->next;
        else
            head = bestCurr->next;

        // add the next best priority to the end of the ordered list
        if (tail != NULL)
            tail->next = bestCurr;
        else
            rtn = bestCurr;

        // set new tail of ordered list
        tail = bestCurr;
        tail->next = NULL;
    }

    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: yeah noticed the build function seemed to congested but I had no idea what to cut out, thanks yours is way simpler. As for the queue function was your addition of the double if needed to switch from the addresses to the actual value as you noted my original code was doing? Working with link list has been troubling sorry if it takes me a while to understand

Comment: The `#if` stuff is the _preprocessor_ [like `#ifdef`] just so you can see a "side-by-side" of original code and fixed code. (i.e. `#if 0 /*original code*/ #else /*fixed code*/ #endif`). Only the fixed code need remain. That is, replace `if (&curr->priority > &largest->priority) {` with `if (curr->priority > largest->priority) {` I didn't check your deeper priority logic, so more issues may remain.

Comment: oh okay I got you, redid it and I'm getting seg faults, i'll work on it tomorrow and update. the priority function while ordering the nodes via priority level also has to change the other info like lastName and reading level to match  their respected priority level info in the new sorted list (so essential all the data has to stick together when rearranged).

Comment: how do I make the createpriority function sort in the opposite order, its form highest to lowest, i need lowest to highest?